# NAs in Ratio Data in addition to "real" zeros

Tags: regression, missing-data, ratio

I have created a ratio dataset - representing the number of rejections/total number of applications. There are some instances in which none of the applications will have been rejected, resulting in a 0 ratio score. However, there are also some instances in which there were no applications, resulting in NAs.

I am undertaking Interrupted Time Series Analysis on this data and therefore need to fit a regression model. I cannot convert NAs to 0 and had previously considered just omitting NA values from the model. However, I assumed someone else would've dealt with this before and might have some advice.

Comment: Definitely omit the "NAs" and clarify in the stat plan that eligible sites had to have at least one applicant. I would NOT directly model the ratio (as per Kronmal's spurious correlation and the fallacy of the ratio). Rather, a standard analysis would model the number of accepted applications using quasipoisson regession with an offset based on the log number of applicants.

Comment: Thanks Adam. Anya advice as to how to use the offset function. My model is currently coded as : glm(`Subject Refused Ratio` ~ Quarter + int2 + time_since_intervention2 , df, family = "binomial"(link='logit')). int2 and time_since_intervention2 being the intervention effects. Would you "offset" the raw 'Subject Refused' in advance and if so how? Sorry for the newbie question......

Comment: Hmm, not the GLM I was suggesting. Would be more like `glm(NRejections ~ <factors> + offset(log(NApplications)), family=quasipoisson)`. Although I'd prefer `NAcceptances` because a. I'm an optimist, and b. receiving more applications means both more rejections and more variability in likelihood of response, true to the Poisson assumption.

Comment: We're testing the effect of a policy, which should lead to an increase in the rate of rejections. AS an ITS study I need to include the intervention terms, but tried with: glm((df$`Subject Refused`+ offset(log(df$`Subject Total`))) ~ Quarter + int2 + time_since_intervention2 , df, family = "quasipoisson"). I'll try adding the offset term in after, but it seriously under-powers the effect - which should reflect a move towards 1 [100% rejections] - when based upon the original ratio....